# Pig latin program, switch/else error

Tags: java, string, io, apache-pig

// I need help with  my else if statement. If the word begins with a vowel, you add way to the end of the word. If the word begins with a  consonant, you put that consonant on the end and add ay.

My problem is if I have a word with a vowel as the first letter, it runs through as if it has a consonant. If I type "are", I get "arewayreaay" instead of "areway".

```
public class piglatin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = IO.    readString();    
        String answer = "";

        if(str.startsWith("a"))
            System.out.print(str + "way");

        if(str.startsWith("e"))
            System.out.print(str + "way");

        if(str.startsWith("i"))
            System.out.print(str + "way");

        if(str.startsWith("o"))
            System.out.print(str + "way");

        if(str.startsWith("u"))
            System.out.print(str + "way");
        else{
            char i = str.charAt(0);
            answer = str.substring( 1, str.length());
            System.out.print(answer + i + "ay");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something that could help reduce this kind of confusion in the future is to put braces around the body of your `if` statement even if it is only 1 line of execution.

Answer (score 6):

```
if(str.startsWith("a") || str.startsWith("e") || str.startsWith("i") ... (and so on)) {
  System.out.print(str + "way"); 
} else{
  char i = str.charAt(0);
  answer = str.substring( 1, str.length());
  System.out.print(answer + i + "ay");
}
```

or if / else if / else

Explanation:

```
//  combine all the if blocks together .. if you dont it checks for vowel 'a' and prints
//  'areay' then it checks for vowel 'u' and enters the else block .. where it again
//  operates on 'are' (check immutability of strings) gets charAt(0) i.e 'a' and prints
//  'rea' and since you concatenated 'ay' ... the final output = 'arewayreaay'
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that each of your leading `if` cases does the same work, and so you can instead collapse all of those into a single branch:

```
if (str.startsWith("a") || str.startsWith("e") || ...
    System.out.print(str + "way");
else
{
    // do the substring and append "ay"
```

Aside from collapsing those branches, your problem is that each of your `if` statements after the first needs an `else`:

```
if(str.startsWith("a"))
    System.out.print(str + "way");
else if(str.startsWith("e"))
    System.out.print(str + "way");
// ...
```

You only want *one* of your branches to execute. But consider what happens in your final `if/else`: you've already modified e.g., `"are"` as the result of your *first* `if` statement. Since you aren't using chained `if/else`, you'll get to your final set of tests:

```
if(str.startsWith("u"))
    System.out.print(str + "way");
else{
```

And you'll end up in the `else` case, since your string *doesn't* start with `"u"`. But you've already handled the string in an earlier `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is not a switch - the `else` is only attaching to the final `if`. Replace each `if` with `else if`, other than the first one, or combine the conditions like jakub suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think your curly braces are messed up. It executes the "if starts with" for 'a' but then also does the "else" for "u" ... so you get both. You may mean:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String str = IO.readString();
    String answer = "";

    if (str.startsWith("a"))
         System.out.print(str + "way");
    else if(str.startsWith("e"))
        System.out.print(str + "way");
    else if(str.startsWith("i"))
        System.out.print(str + "way");
    else if(str.startsWith("o"))
        System.out.print(str + "way");
    else if(str.startsWith("u"))
        System.out.print(str + "way");
    else
    {
        char i = str.charAt(0);
        answer = str.substring( 1, str.length());
        System.out.print(answer + i + "ay");
    }
}
```